# TSQL left join and only last row from right

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I'm writing sql query to get post and only last comment of this post(if exists).
But I can't find a way to limit only 1 row for right column in left join.

Here is sample of this query.

```
SELECT post.id, post.title,comment.id,comment.message
from post
left outer join comment
on post.id=comment.post_id
```

If post has 3 comments I get 3 rows with this post, but I want only 1 row with last comment(ordered by date).

Can somebody help me with this query?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
SELECT  post.id, post.title, comment.id, comment.message
FROM    post
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    comment с
        WHERE   c.post_id = post.id
        ORDER BY
                date DESC
        ) comment
```

or

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  post.id, post.title, comment.id, comment.message,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY post.id ORDER BY comment.date DESC) AS rn
        FROM    post
        LEFT JOIN
                comment
        ON      comment.post_id = post.id
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

The former is more efficient for few posts with many comments in each; the latter is more efficient for many posts with few comments in each.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I use next code.

SELECT post.id, post.title,c.id as comment_id,c.message
from post
left outer join (select comment.id,comment.post_id,comment.message,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY comment.post_id ORDER BY comment.date DESC) AS rn
 from comment) c
on post.id=c.post_id
where c.rn=1 or c.rn is null

Comment: The APPLY operator did the trick for me.  I was making a 1-to-many join, but needed to reduce the right side matches down to only the most recently created.  Thanks!

Comment: It is interesting to put this two together to show the estimated query plan, the `apply` option was 99% of the query cost :o

Comment: @FelipeSabino: If you see a "buffalo" sign on an elephant's cage, do not trust your eyes.

Answer (score 19):

Subquery:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, c.id, c.message
FROM post p
LEFT join comment c
ON c.post_id = p.id AND c.id = 
                 (SELECT MAX(c2.id) FROM comment c2 WHERE c2.post_id = p.id)
```

Comment: If I'm not missing something this should be much faster (like 10x times) to execute than accepted answer judging by my execution plan.

Comment: Also to me this seems far more efficient than the usage of the bulky sub queries used in the accepted answer. There's a related answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692419/how-do-i-join-the-first-row-of-a-subquery. It uses a TOP 1/ORDER BY solution instead of MAX in the sub query.

Comment: I believe this is the shorter and better answer.

Comment: This will return last comment when ordered by ID, not by date as OP requested

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to join to a sub-query that returns the last comment for the post.  For example:

```
select post.id, post.title. lastpostid, lastcommentmessage
from post
inner join
(
    select post.id as lastpostid, max(comment.id) as lastcommentmessage
    from post
    inner join comment on commment.post_id = post.id
    group by post.id
) lastcomment
    on lastpostid = post.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options....

One way is to do the JOIN on:

```
SELECT TOP 1 comment.message FROM comment ORDER BY comment.id DESC
```

(note I'm assuming that comment.id is an Identity field)

Comment: what if Identity field has a negative increment?

Comment: have you ever come across such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

what version of SQL Server?  If you have the Row_Number() function available you can sort your comments by whatever "first" means to you and then just add a "where RN=1" clause.  Don't have a handy example or the right syntax off the top of my head but do have tons of queries that do exactly this.  Other posts are all in the 1,000's of ways you could do this.

I'd say profile it and see which one performs best for you.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say the specific name of your date field, so I filled in with `[DateCreated]`.  This is essentially the same as AGoodDisplayName's post above, but using the date field instead of relying on the ID column ordering.

```
SELECT post.id, post.title, comment.id, comment.message
FROM post p
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment
ON comment.id = (
    SELECT TOP 1 id
    FROM comment
    WHERE p.id = post_id
    ORDER BY [DateCreated] ASC
)
```